# c# adding values to a sorted node based list

Tags: c#, nodes

Im trying to make an 'Add(int n)' method to add a node to a node based list. the list is sorted and i want to add the node in the right place so it will still be sorted after adding the node.

example:

current node list values: 1 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 5
value to add: 2
result: 1 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 3 - 5

i made a class called : nodeList
my code:

```
class NodeList
    {
        private int head;
        private NodeList tail;

        public NodeList(int head, NodeList tail)
        {
            this.head = head;
            this.tail = tail;
        }

        public NodeList Add(int n)
        {
            NodeList nl = new NodeList(head, tail);
            NodeList result = null;
            if (nl.head > n)
                result = new NodeList(n, nl);
            else
            {
                 //cant figure this part out
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Adding a node when 'n' is smaller than the first element in the node based list was easy to figure out, but i just cant seem to figure out how to do it if its not the case.

extra information:

the list can include duplicates.
the class NodeList cant have more instance variables than the ones i included.

Comment: try using a List<int>. Add values and sort it whenever user calls Add(int n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep this immutable and always want to create new instance,  else part can have this:

```
            nl.tail = nl.tail == null ? new NodeList(n, null) : nl.tail.Add(n);
            return nl;
```

Comment: He wants the list to be sorted.

Comment: List would be sorted. When the Add would be called on tail, check would run recursively to reach correct tail to be replaced.

Comment: this works great and is actually exactly what i need, since it doesnt have to have both a private and a public method, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use your structure you can use the following code. It uses a recursive function to iterate over the different elements up to the correct node.

```
public class NodeList
{
    public int Head { get; }
    public NodeList Tail { get; set; }

    public NodeList(int head, NodeList tail)
    {
        Head = head;
        Tail = tail;
    }

    private NodeList Add(int value, NodeList current)
    {
        var nextNode = current.Tail;

        if (nextNode == null)
        {
            current.Tail = new NodeList(value, null);
            return current.Tail;
        }

        if (nextNode.Head > value)
        {
            current.Tail = new NodeList(value, nextNode);
            return current.Tail;
        }

        // Recursive
        return Add(value, nextNode);
    }

    public NodeList Add(int value)
    {
        if (value < this.Head)
        {
            var newRoot = new NodeList(value, this);
            return newRoot;
        }

        Add(value, this);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: can this be done with only 1 parameter in the Add method aswell?

Comment: There is only 1 parameter to the public `Add` method. `public NodeList Add(int value)`

Comment: Is it what you wanted?

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me, i have a list with the values: {1 3 3 5 6}
but when i call list = list.Add(5) it will eventually turn the list into {5, 6}

Comment: But this is a linked list, you don't need to return the NodeList, I did return the newly created item because it seemed that it is what you wanted but what is returned is the new node. When inserting into a list that does not have a reference to the previous item you will always want to perform your operations from the Root Element (1).

Comment: Ok let me change the code, so that it returns the root element of the linked list.

Comment: the new node has to be inserted in the right place of the list so basicly:
before we call Add: {1,2,3,4}
now we call Add(0): {0,1,2,3,4}
now we call Add(2): {0,1,2,2,3,4}